# Python import reports no module named when I import a local script

Tags: python, flask, import

I am trying to import scripts into my main.py script. It tells me the sub folder where i keep my other scripts doesn't exsist.

file structure

```
- root_folder
  --modules
   ---models.py
   ---database.py
  --main.py
```

I know my import code is spelt correctly vs code even autocompletes it. I have added modules folder to my PYTHONPATH and I am using flask to execute everything.

```
`from modules.models import User`
```

thats the problem line

As stated I made sure everything is spelt correctly, all folders are in my PYTHONPATH. My modules folder has an `__init__.py` and so does my main folder.

Comment: @binaryescape OP says that the folders are in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I build the file structure without adding anything to PYTHONPATH. It worked when running main.py as a top level script because its directory is automatically added to sys.path. Any chance you have a different "modules" out there somewhere. Can you `import modules;print(modules.__file__)`?

Comment: And can you post the full traceback message? We don't even know the name of the failed import.

Comment: Well, if you added *modules* to PYTHONPATH then you should do `from models import User` instead. But adding to PYTHONPATH shouldn't be necessary - you're probably not running Python from your project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
from root_folder.modules.models import User
```

This worked for me.